# Dynamically change the grid inside dashboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lightningchart

I am using LightningChartJs with react and would like to dynamically change the grid of the dashboard without refreshing the chart or without disturbing the charts operation in hand.Right now I am trying to set the grid settings with conditional checks but since the createChart method runs only at the start it does not refresh.

Thanks in advance.

Edit :

As a workaround I managed the grid on my own with bootstrap.

Comment: If you don't mind can you share your method of managing custom grid with bootstrap?

Comment: @Chandana thanks but I've already done that :)

Comment: Can you share how you were able to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LightningChart JS currently doesn't support editing the number of columns or rows in the grid after creation. Also there is no method to move a chart to a another grid cell after creation.